# How can I create an owning pointer to an unsized type?

Tags: pointers, rust

Dealing with values of type `str` in Rust is clumsy because they do not implement the trait `Sized`. Therefore, they can only be accessed by pointer.

For my application, using ordinary pointers with lifetimes is not very helpful. Rather, I want an owning fat pointer that guarantees that the contained object will last as long as the pointer does (and no longer), but allows holding values of unknown size.

Comment: Is there a reason you are unable to use `String` or `Vec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Box<T>` works for an unsized `T`; thus `Box<str>`, `Box<[T]>` and so forth. The important distinction to note between `Box<str>` and `String` is that the latter has a capacity member as well, increasing its memory usage by one word but allowing for efficient appending as it may not need to reallocate for every push, whereas a similar method on a `Box<str>` would need to. The same is true of `Box<[T]>` versus `Vec<T>`, with the former being a fixed-size slice while the latter is conveniently growable. Unlike `Box<str>`, `Box<[T]>` *is* actually used in real life; the `vec!` macro uses it for efficiency, as a `Box<[T]>` can be written out literally and then converted to a `Vec<T>` at no cost.